# Android Studio data xml file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am looking at tutorials and for some reason I can not find the mysharedpremain.xml file. In my android studio I dont have a data tab.

Can somebody help? The image of the tutorial is below

Thank you
[image: http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/M2l72us.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such tab called data in android studio. data/data is the place where the android system stores your application and it's related fies,To see your application and related files you need to access the android file system.

In order to do that follow the below steps

1. Run your app in an  emulator or in a rooted android device
2. open android device monitor as described in the image you posted
3. on the left side of the window you will  see devices tab click on the   emulator/device on which your app is currently running.
4. Click on file explorer tab and select data folder inside that you will find one more data folder select it and search for package name that matches your app package name and expand it..you will find your preference file if you  already created one